# laravel-ide-helper does not work in api.php but works fine in web.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

After Installation of [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) I found that I can not navigate to controller methods by `ctrl+click` on the name of controller only in `api.php` file.  while that works fine in `web.php` routes file.

Of course I'm using [dingo laravel package](https://github.com/dingo/api)  and all defined routes are like this :

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
    $api->post('Profile', ['as' => 'Profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile']);
    $api->post('getEditProfile', ['uses' => 'loginController@getEditProfile']);
    $api->post('UpdateProfile', ['uses' => 'loginController@UpdateProfile']);
    });
```

Could this be problematic?